# Custom Docusign Destination URLs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm struggling to get a callback for custom Destination URLs configured in Docusign.

Document signed callback works fine, but not 'Finish Later' or 'Decline'.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you use the branding feature to do this? how do you set the brand?

Comment: yes, edit brand -> destunation urls

Comment: but how do you apply the brand to the envelope?

Comment: It's a single brand and showing as default in UI, I don't think it needs to be assigned to envelope every time.

Comment: I just tried with a brand that was assigned to the envelope - and it works just fine. Can you try that just so I know that worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we figured out what was wrong:

1. there was a significant delay for us when we changed values for Destination URLs
2. we were testing with the same email for sender and receiver, thus couldn't see a 'decline' option; when started using different email for the receiver - the option become visible, and we could get a callback from DocuSign.

Thank you guys for trying to help and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all URLs start with **https**!

You need to set your brand as default like this:

(right click it and set it as default)

I confirmed this works this way as well as by selecting a specific brand when you send.

[image]

Comment: We use https. I posted an explanation of what wasn't working for us. Thanks Inbar!

Answer (score 1):

From DocuSign Developer Support,

- There can be a delay between setting the URLs and when it takes effect, recommendation would be to wait a few minutes prior to testing.
- For testing try stetting unique URLs for each event, such as:

example.com/signing-complete
vs
example.com/finish-later

- Also checking the ?event= parameter to make sure it aligns with what action was taken.
- "F12 -> Network tab" will allow the user to see what exactly is happening during the redirect/landing process.
  e.g. If a dynamic landing page is immediately redirecting the user to somewhere else.

Best regards,
Conar | DocuSign Developer Support